# Programmatically list AdSense pages with policy violations

Tags: google-adsense

I have several pages of policy violations for Google AdSense that are marked as "must fix". Is there a way to programmatically get those pages so I can remove the AdSense code on them?

Comment: Do you mean have adsense spit out a list of pages that are violating policy?

Comment: @Steve yes some kind of API that can return a list of pages Or do we have to resort to webscraping?